# Unknown protocol to job tracker

Tags: hadoop, datastax-enterprise

I'm attempting to run a Hadoop mapreduce job within DataStax 3.1 and getting this error. Any ideas on what's the cause?

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to job tracker: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getProtocolVersion(JobTracker.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcc

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Hadoop source documentation:

> `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol` is used by user code via `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` class to communicate with the NameNode.

DSE does not come with NameNodes nor DataNodes - they are part of Apache Hadoop HDFS and in DSE they have been replaced by Cassandra File System.

The stacktrace states you are using HDFS protocol to connect to the JobTracker node, which suggests you are incorrectly sumbitting your jobs.

With DSE you should submit your M/R jobs by invoking:

```
dse hadoop jar <your M/R jar file> <your M/R main class> [args]
```

And to access the Cassandra File System:

```
dse hadoop fs <file system command> [args]
```

You can find more information in the [DSE Hadoop Documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/hadoop_index).